# Custom layer with Keras: Is it possible to have output neurons set to 0 in the output of a softmax layer based on zeros as data in an input layer?

Tags: backend, keras-layer, softmax

I have a neural network with 13 output neurons in the last layer using softmax activation (soft_out). I also know exactly that based on the input values, certain neurons in the output layer shall have 0 values. So I have a special input layer (inp) of 13 neurons, each of them being either 0 or 1.

Would it be somehow possible to force let's say the output neuron no. 3 to have value = 0 if the input neuron no 3 is set to 1?

In addition to this it must act as a softmax layer, so at the end the sum of the neurons must be 1.  Thus the output rows must be corrected.

The steps are as follows:
1. clear soft_out neurons where inp neurons==1
2. calculate sum of the rows in soft_out 
3. check in which row where the sum is 0
4. correct soft_out in the rows where sum is 0 to an arbitrary constant value
5. calculate sum of the rows in soft_out again
6. check in which row where the sum is 0 and set it to 1
7. return soft_out / sum per each row (so adjust the output to have sum =1 per row)

With numpy these are the steps:
INPUT DATA

```
inp = np.array((5,13))
inp = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=5*13, p=[.5, .5])
inp = inp.reshape(5,13)
soft_out=np.around(np.random.random_sample((5,13)),2)
inp [3,:]=1
inp [4,:]=1
inp [4,12]=0
soft_out[4,12]=0
print ("inp",inp,"\n")
print ("soft_out",soft_out,"\n")
```

> inp [[1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]  [1 0 1
>   1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 0]]
>
> soft_out [[0.8  0.16 0.42 0.44 0.67 0.39 0.38 0.54 0.75 0.06 0.62 0.67
>   0.86]  [0.87 0.28 0.51 0.92 0.89 0.97 0.1  0.17 0.73 0.43 0.84 0.96 0.57]  [0.16 0.33 0.62 0.37 0.42 0.54 0.1  0.54 0.92 0.51 0.89 0.86 0.96]  [0.53 0.59 0.6  0.63 0.57 0.95 0.41 0.1  0.32 0.81 0.87 0.35 0.16]  [0.13 0.57 0.92 0.87 0.82 0.08 0.74 0.78 0.2  0.22 0.64 0.06 0.  ]]

```
#0. find out where inp is set to 1 and to 0
mask_nonzero=np.where(inp != 0 )
print ("mask_nonzero", mask_nonzero,"\n")

mask_zero=np.where(inp == 0 )
print ("mask_zero", mask_zero,"\n")

#1. clear those values where inp is 1
soft_out[mask_nonzero]=0
print ("soft_out", soft_out,"\n")

#2. calculate the sum of the rows
row_sum_soft_out = np.sum(soft_out,axis=-1)
print ("row_sum_soft_out", row_sum_soft_out,"\n")

# 3. reshape in order to find out rows where the sum is zero >> this means that the soft_out values have to be corrected
row_sum_soft_out = row_sum_soft_out.reshape(5,1)
print ("row_sum_soft_out", row_sum_soft_out,"\n")

mask_sum_zero = np.where(row_sum_soft_out == 0 )
soft_out[mask_sum_zero[0]] = 1
print ("soft_out", soft_out,"\n")

print ("mask_sum_zero", mask_sum_zero,"\n")
soft_out[mask_nonzero]=0

# correct soft_out in the rows where sum is 0 to an arbitrary constant value
row_sum_soft_out = np.sum(soft_out,axis=-1)

#5. calculate sum of the rows in soft_out again
mask_sum_zero = np.where(row_sum_soft_out == 0 )

#6. check in which row where the sum is 0 and set it to 1
row_sum_soft_out[mask_sum_zero] = 1

row_sum_soft_out = row_sum_soft_out.reshape(5,1)
#7. return soft_out / sum per each row (so adjust the output to have sum =1 per row)
y = soft_out / row_sum_soft_out
print ("soft_out", y)
print (np.sum(y,axis=-1),"\n")
```

> mask_nonzero (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
>          3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
>         dtype=int64), array([ 0,  1,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  4,  8,  9, 12,  0,  2,  3,  7, 12,
>           0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,  0,  1,  2,  3,
>           4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int64))
>
> mask_zero (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
>   2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
>          4], dtype=int64), array([ 2,  3, 10, 11, 12,  0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11,  1,  4,  5,
>           6,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12], dtype=int64))
>
> soft_out [[0.   0.   0.42 0.44 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.62 0.67
>   0.86]  [0.87 0.28 0.51 0.92 0.   0.97 0.1  0.17 0.   0.   0.84 0.96 0.  ]  [0.   0.33 0.   0.   0.42 0.54 0.1  0.   0.92 0.51 0.89 0.86 0.  ] 
>   [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ] 
>   [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]]
>
> row_sum_soft_out [3.01 5.62 4.57 0.   0.  ]
>
> row_sum_soft_out [[3.01]  [5.62]  [4.57]  [0.  ]  [0.  ]]
>
> soft_out [[0.   0.   0.42 0.44 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.62 0.67
>   0.86]  [0.87 0.28 0.51 0.92 0.   0.97 0.1  0.17 0.   0.   0.84 0.96 0.  ]  [0.   0.33 0.   0.   0.42 0.54 0.1  0.   0.92 0.51 0.89 0.86 0.  ] 
>   [1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.  ] 
>   [1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.  ]]
>
> mask_sum_zero (array([3, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0], dtype=int64))
>
> soft_out [[0.         0.         0.13953488 0.1461794  0.         0.
>     0.         0.         0.         0.         0.20598007 0.22259136
>     0.28571429]  [0.15480427 0.04982206 0.09074733 0.16370107 0.         0.17259786
>     0.01779359 0.03024911 0.         0.         0.14946619 0.17081851
>     0.        ]  [0.         0.07221007 0.         0.         0.09190372 0.11816193
>     0.02188184 0.         0.20131291 0.11159737 0.19474836 0.18818381
>     0.        ]  [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
>     0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
>     0.        ]  [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
>     0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
>     1.        ]] [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]

Can someone please help be write the KERAS backend layer please?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code at the end ... one should change the shape (shape=(32, 13)) as needed

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
def mask_output2(x):
    # soft_out is the output of the previous softmax layer, shape =(batch_size, 13) in my case
    # inp is the tensor containing 0 and 1-s, where 1 means that the action was already used, shape=(batch_size, 13)
    inp, soft_out = x
    # add a very small value in order to avoid having 0 everywhere
    c = K.constant(0.0000001, dtype='float32', shape=(32, 13))
    y = soft_out + c
    # clear invalid actions' values
    y = Lambda(lambda x: K.switch(K.equal(x[0],0), x[1], K.zeros_like(x[1])))([inp, soft_out])
    y_sum =  K.sum(y, axis=-1)
    # correct sum if it is 0 to avoid dividing by zero
    y_sum_corrected = Lambda(lambda x: K.switch(K.equal(x[0],0), K.ones_like(x[0]), x[0] ))([y_sum])
    # reshape output in order to have sum 1 per row, so first calculate 1/sum
    y_sum_corrected = tf.divide(1,y_sum_corrected)
    # multiply tensor (32,13) with tensor (32)
    y = tf.einsum('ij,i->ij', y, y_sum_corrected)
    return y
```